# Call a class of a span tag using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

I built an HTML file with two p tags that hold the text and the source of a quote. I put the sources and quotes in an object array. I also have a third optional property for the objects which is the year. However, when I try to call the class of the span tag, I get the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

If I change the `<span>` tags to `<p>` tags then the error goes away. How do I call upon a span tag using query selector?

```js
/*** 
 * `quotes` array 
***/
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: 'The greatest wealth is to live content with little.',
    source: 'Plato',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Don\'t count the days, make the days count.',
    source: 'Muhammad Ali',
  },
  {
    quote: 'You miss 100% of the shots you don\'t take.',
    source: 'Wayne Gretzky',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Ask not what your country can do for you. Ask what you can do for your country.',
    source: 'John F. Kennedy',
    year: '1961'
  },
  {
    quote: 'Test quote',
    source: 'test source',
  }
]


/***
 * `getRandomQuote` function
***/
const getRandomQuote = (numOfQuotes) =>{
  const randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * numOfQuotes));
  return quotes[randomnumber];
}

/***
 * `printQuote` function
***/
const printQuote = () =>{
  const quoteObject = getRandomQuote(quotes.length);
  const quoteText = document.querySelector('.quote');
  const quoteSource = document.querySelector('.source');
  const quoteYear = document.querySelector('.year');
  quoteText.innerHTML = quoteObject.quote;
  quoteSource.innerHTML = quoteObject.source;
  if (quoteObject.year){
    quoteYear.innerHTML = quoteObject.year;
  }
}


/***
 * click event listener for the print quote button
 * DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!!
***/

document.getElementById('load-quote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Quotes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
      <button id="load-quote" class="load-quote">Show another quote</button>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="quote-box" class="quote-box">
        <p class="quote">Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.</p>
        <p class="source">Patrick McKenzie<span class="citation">Twitter</span><span class="year">2016</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put the code that *doesn't* work in your question. I'm 99.9% sure this is a typo issue, because replacing `<p>` with `<span>` will make zero difference with regard to your JS code. Edit: your `.year` element is *inside* the `.source` element. Which means when you update the source part, you lose the year span.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed span out of p tag as `quoteSource.innerHTML = ...` will change innerHTML of source with p tag.

```js
/*** 
 * `quotes` array 
***/
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: 'The greatest wealth is to live content with little.',
    source: 'Plato',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Don\'t count the days, make the days count.',
    source: 'Muhammad Ali',
  },
  {
    quote: 'You miss 100% of the shots you don\'t take.',
    source: 'Wayne Gretzky',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Ask not what your country can do for you. Ask what you can do for your country.',
    source: 'John F. Kennedy',
    year: '1961'
  },
  {
    quote: 'Test quote',
    source: 'test source',
  }
]


/***
 * `getRandomQuote` function
***/
const getRandomQuote = (numOfQuotes) =>{
  const randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * numOfQuotes));
  return quotes[randomnumber];
}

/***
 * `printQuote` function
***/
const printQuote = () =>{
  const quoteObject = getRandomQuote(quotes.length);
  const quoteText = document.querySelector('.quote');
  const quoteSource = document.querySelector('.source');
  const quoteYear = document.querySelector('.year');
  quoteText.innerHTML = quoteObject.quote;
  quoteSource.innerHTML = quoteObject.source; // THIS CODE IS WILL REMOVE SPAN
  if (quoteObject.year){
    quoteYear.innerHTML = quoteObject.year;
  }
  else {
   quoteYear.innerHTML = ""
  }
}


/***
 * click event listener for the print quote button
 * DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!!
***/

document.getElementById('load-quote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
      <button id="load-quote" class="load-quote">Show another quote</button>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="quote-box" class="quote-box">
        <p class="quote">Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.</p>
        <p class="source">Patrick McKenzie<span class="citation">Twitter</span></p><span class="year">2016</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**
IF you have to put span inside P tag only, here is another working solution for it,

```js
/*** 
 * `quotes` array 
***/
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: 'The greatest wealth is to live content with little.',
    source: 'Plato',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Don\'t count the days, make the days count.',
    source: 'Muhammad Ali',
  },
  {
    quote: 'You miss 100% of the shots you don\'t take.',
    source: 'Wayne Gretzky',
  },
  {
    quote: 'Ask not what your country can do for you. Ask what you can do for your country.',
    source: 'John F. Kennedy',
    year: '1961'
  },
  {
    quote: 'Test quote',
    source: 'test source',
  }
]


/***
 * `getRandomQuote` function
***/
const getRandomQuote = (numOfQuotes) =>{
  const randomnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * numOfQuotes));
  return quotes[randomnumber];
}

/***
 * `printQuote` function
***/
const printQuote = () =>{
  const quoteObject = getRandomQuote(quotes.length);
  const quoteText = document.querySelector('.quote');
  const quoteSource = document.querySelector('.source');
  const quoteYear = document.querySelector('.year');
  quoteText.innerHTML = quoteObject.quote;
 [].reduce.call(quoteSource.childNodes, function(a, b) { return (b.nodeType === 3 ? b.textContent = quoteObject.source : ''); }, '');
  if (quoteObject.year){
    quoteYear.innerHTML = quoteObject.year;
  }
  else {
   quoteYear.innerHTML = ""
  }
}


/***
 * click event listener for the print quote button
 * DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!!
***/

document.getElementById('load-quote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```html
<header>
      <h1>Random Quotes</h1>
      <button id="load-quote" class="load-quote">Show another quote</button>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="quote-box" class="quote-box">
        <p class="quote">Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.</p>
        <p class="source">Patrick McKenzie<span class="citation">Twitter</span><span class="year">2016</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get a child of .source
so u should use this selector:
`const quoteYear = document.querySelector('.source .year');`
that would work great!

Answer (score 0):

You have element year as a child to source div and your code is replacing the content of source after every button click
Ultimately element with the class year is not going to be there in the DOM after the first click

```
const quoteSource = document.querySelector('.source');
quoteSource.innerHTML = quoteObject.source;
```

and hence

`document.querySelector('.year')` returns null and ultimately
'quoteYear.innerHTML' throws innerHTML of null